# How to extract and compare bytes from JMeter JMS Subscriber Response Body

Tags: java, arrays, jmeter, jms, publish-subscribe

I send request (bytes from file) by JMS Publisher [(JMS Publisher screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCKdh.png), read response by JMS Subscriber 
[(JMS Subscriber screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl5Jz.png) and try to compare request and response data via BeanShell Assertion in this way [(BeanShell Assertion screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYDqD.png):

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

Path path = Paths.get("${pathToTesting}/queries/randomBytes/randomBytes.dat", new String[0]);
byte[] originalArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
byte[] changedArray = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData();
System.out.println(changedArray.length);
if (Arrays.equals(originalArray, changedArray))
{
    System.out.println("same!");

} else {
    System.out.println("diff!");
     SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Comparison failed");
     SampleResult.setResponseData("Byte arrays has changed after sending through connectors","UTF-8");
    IsSuccess=false;
}
```

In View Result Tree (in JMS Subscriber) I see

> 5000 bytes received in BytesMessage

And question is HOW to get ACTUAL 5000 bytes (NOT a message "5000 bytes received in BytesMessage") and compare it with original bytes I send via JMS Publisher?

I need a re-configure samplers\assertion or just refactore a code?

I will be thankfull for any help and relevant links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into [JMSSampler class source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_0/src/protocol/jms/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jms/sampler/JMSSampler.java#L368) I fail to see how you can get the actual response content without modifying the aforementioned class as it appears to be discarded therefore you will not be able to assert it.

```
} else if (msg instanceof BytesMessage) {
    BytesMessage bytesMessage = (BytesMessage) msg;
    buffer.append(bytesMessage.getBodyLength() + " bytes received in BytesMessage");
}
```

You create an [enhancement request](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) and there is a chance it will be included in the next release or at least modify your assertion logic to compare size of the sent message with the received one.

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to switch to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) on next available opportunity.